# Why won't my Macbook Pro exit closed-clamshell mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, screen, closed-clamshell

I often connect my MacBook Pro to external monitors. When it's plugged into power, I can close the lid and it turns off the MacBook monitor and goes into closed clamshell mode, no problem.

But it often won't *exit* closed-clamshell mode when I open up the MacBook again (or unplug the external monitors). Usually when I open the MacBook, the Touch Bar lights up fine, but the screen stays completely black. The only way I can figure out to turn the screen back on is to completely restart the computer (which I have to do unsafely by holding down the power button, since I can't use the monitor). It's obviously extremely annoying to have to restart my computer most of the times that I disconnect it from my external monitors.

What's worse is that this behavior doesn't always occur - I'd estimate that it occurs about 75% of the time, and the other 25% of the time when I open my laptop lid from closed-clamshell mode, the Macbook screen turns back on as normal. So I suspect that it's probably a hardware issue. (The weird thing is that the Touch Bar lights up every time I open the lid, so clearly some part of the computer is realizing that the lid is open.)

Any suggestions? Failing a complete fix, how can I tell the MacBook to turn the screen back on? (The laptop itself is still on, because the Touch Bar works fine, but the screen is black.) I've tried pushing keys on the keyboard and on the Touch Bar, but nothing works.

2018 15-inch Macbook Pro running MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Using the latest software (Catalina) might be worth a shot - are you averse to upgrading?

Comment: @JBallin Unfortunately, upgrading isn't an option for me for the time being.

Comment: Maybe try resetting the SMC and see if that helps: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: This happens to me too. In fact, this is happening to me right now :/. It is worthless to have to restart the machine. I'm trying to find a way NOT to have to restart it.

Comment: This is by far NOT a solution, but because I'm using my fingerprint to open my mac and because my current desktop setup allows it, I settled with: 1. leave mac semi opened (enough to fit hand to input fingerprint), 2. mirror displays, 3. dim laptop to 0% brightness. This works because it is NOT closed clamshell mode. The cons are that the graphics card is most likely still processing BOTH displays regardless of the 0% brightness, although it is not an issue for me as I'm only using the mac for work (not too heavy on the rendering side). I hope this idea helps some people.